# How do i group headings of page in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have successfully created the page as i want however, i have tried all the tutorials here and none worked

I want them displayed as group date for the same date:

**Role   -- -----   Name  -- --- Date**
2018-05-20
Truck ------   David -------2018-05-20:56:09
Services --  Kevin-------  2018-05-21:55:54
Food -------      Sam -------  2018-05-21:55:35

2018-05-20
Driving  ---- Ahmed  ------2018-05-21:55:35

Never mind the "-----"

So here's what i have done
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHmGB.png)

and my code is

```html
<?php 
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$group_date = null;
if ($group_date !== substr($r["date"], 0, 10))
$group_date = substr($r["date"], 0, 10);
> 
<tr><td><p><?= $group_date ?></p></td></tr>
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $r['role'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $r['name']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $r['date']; ?></td> 
</tr> 
<?php } ?>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

My select statement is

```html
SELECT * FROM `users` GROUP BY date DESC
```

Comment: GROUP BY DATE(date)  try that

Comment: Save the formatted date for each item into a variable. If it changes, output a new headline.

Comment: Just looking at that i knew it wont work Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: @Spingolini Could you give me a sample.. im stuck

Comment: I guess  you need `ORDER BY` but not `GROUP BY`

Comment: You can't order at sql level alone you need to manipulate the php file and the code below does it well.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not the prettiest solution out there, but it'll do it's job.

Basically, what it does, it checks if the date from the current item is different from the date stored in `$group_date`. If so, it outputs the date as a header for the next columns and stores it back in `$group_date`.

```
<?php
$group_date = null;
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $date = substr($r["date"], 0, 10);

    if ($group_date !== $date) {
        $group_date = $date;
        echo '<tr><td colspan="3"><p>' . $date . '</p></td></tr>';
    }

    echo <<<ROW
<tr>
    <td>{$r['role']}</td>
    <td>{$r['name']}</td>
    <td>{$r['date']}</td>
</tr>
ROW;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```